# Universal metadata in video files for scene, take, etc

Tags: video, metadata

Is there any universal format for video metadata containing information such as the scene and take? `XMP` appears to be exclusively for Adobe products (Premiere Pro). I'm looking for some metadata format that will be recognized in both FCP & Premiere (and maybe even Avid if possible).